# Lang's treatment of product of Radon measures

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
We denote by $\mathcal B(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of $X$.
A positive Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal B(X)$ with the following properties.

(1) $\mu(K) \lt \infty$ for all compact sets $K$.

(2) For any $E\in \mathcal B(X)$, $\mu(E) = \text{inf}\ \mu(U)$ for all open $U$ such that $E \subset U$.

(3) For any open $U$, $\mu(U) = \sup\ \mu(K)$ for all compact $K$ such that $K \subset U$.

It can be proved(see, for example, Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*) that a positive Radon measure has the following property.

(3') For any $\sigma$-finite set $E\in \mathcal B(X)$, $\mu(E) = \sup\ \mu(K)$ for all compact $K$ such that $K \subset E$.

Now let $\mu, \nu$ be positive Radon measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$.
We denote by $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(Y)$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ containg all the sets of the form $A\times B, A\in \mathcal B(X), B \in \mathcal B(Y)$.
Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite.
Let $\mu\otimes \nu$ be the product measure on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(Y)$.
Let $f:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous function with compact support.
It can be proved using Stone-Weierstrass theorem that $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(Y)$. Hence it is integrable with respect to $\mu\otimes \nu$.
Hence $f \rightarrow \int f d(\mu\otimes\nu)$ is a positive linear functional defined on the vector space of continuous functions of compact support on $X\times Y$.
By Riesz representation theorem there is a unique positive Radon measure $\lambda$ on $X\times Y$ such that $\int f d(\mu\otimes\nu) = \int f d\lambda$ for all continuous functions of compact support on $X\times Y$.
Lang claims without explanation in his book Real and Functional Analysis that $\lambda$ and $\mu\otimes\nu$ coincide on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(Y)$(Th. 6.3, Ch. IX, Sect. 7, p.274).
I don't understand why this is so.
Would anyone elaborate on this?

**EDIT(29 July 2015)**
For the convenience of the reader, I reproduce Theorem 6.3 and its proof in Lang's book.

**Theorem 6.3**.
Let $X, Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces and let $\mu, \nu$ be positive $\sigma$-regular Borel measures on $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
Assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite with respect to these measures.
Then all functions in $C_c(X\times Y)$ are in $\mathcal L^1(\mu\otimes\nu)$, and there exists a unique $\sigma$-regular Borel measure on $X\times Y$  which restricts to $\mu\otimes\nu$ on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes\mathcal B(Y)$.

*Proof*.
Lemma 6.1 shows that functions in $C_c(X\times Y)$ are $(\mu\otimes\nu)$-measurable,
and combined with Fubini's theorem shows that these functions are in $\mathcal L^1(\mu\otimes\nu)$.
The map $f \rightarrow \int_{X\times Y} f d(\mu\otimes\nu)$ is obviously a positive functional on $C_c(X\times Y)$, and we can therefore apply Theorem 2.3 to get a $\sigma$-regular Borel measure having the desired properties. The Corollary 2.8 gives the uniquness, thus proving our theorem.

**Remark**.
Lemma 6.1 just proves by using Stone-Weierstrass theorem that functions in $C_c(X\times Y)$ are $(\mu\otimes\nu)$-measurable.
Theorem 2.3 is a part of Riesz representation theorem.
A $\sigma$-regular Borel measure is just a positive Radon measure in our terminology.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274411/is-riesz-measure-an-extension-of-product-measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $K\subset X$ and $L\subset Y$ be compact and let $U\subset X\times Y$
be open with $K\times L\subset U$. Then there are open sets $V\subset X$
and $W\subset Y$ with
$$
K\times L\subset V\times W\subset U.
$$
**Proof**: For each $\left(x,y\right)\in K\times L$ there are -- by definition
of the product topology -- open sets $V_{x,y}\subset X$ and $W_{x,y}\subset Y$
with $\left(x,y\right)\in V_{x,y}\times W_{x,y}\subset U$.

By compactness of $K$, there is thus for each $y\in L$ some $n_{y}\in\mathbb{N}$
and suitable $x_{1}^{\left(y\right)},\dots,x_{n_{y}}^{\left(y\right)}\in X$
with 
$$
K\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_{y}}V_{x_{i}^{\left(y\right)},y}=:V_{y}.
$$
Note that
$$
W_{y}:=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n_{y}}W_{x_{i}^{\left(y\right)},y}\subset Y
$$
is open with $y\in W_{y}$. By compactness of $L$, there are thus
$y_{1},\dots,y_{m}\in L$ with $L\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^{m}W_{y_{j}}=:W$.
Set
$$
V:=\bigcap_{j=1}^{m}V_{y_{j}}
$$
and note that $V\subset X$ and $W\subset Y$ are open with $K\times L\subset V\times W$,
so that it remains to show $V\times W\subset U$.

To this end, let $\left(x,y\right)\in V\times W$ be arbitrary. By
definition of $W$, there is $j\in\left\{ 1,\dots,m\right\} $ with
$y\in W_{y_{j}}$. By definition of $V$, we have $x\in V_{y_{j}}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_{y}}V_{x_{i}^{\left(y_{j}\right)},y_{j}}$
and hence $x\in V_{x_{i}^{\left(y_{j}\right)},y_{j}}$ for some $i\in\left\{ 1,\dots,n_{y}\right\} $.
But by definition of $W_{y_{j}}$, we have $y\in W_{x_{i}^{\left(y_{j}\right)},y_{j}}$
and hence $\left(x,y\right)\in V_{x_{i}^{\left(y_{j}\right)},y_{j}}\times W_{x_{i}^{\left(y_{j}\right)},y_{j}}\subset U$. $\square$

Now, we can use the usual proof to show $\lambda\left(K\times L\right)=\mu\left(K\right)\nu\left(L\right)$
for all compact $K,L$. Let $\varepsilon\in\left(0,1\right)$ be arbitrary.
By regularity, there are open sets $U\subset X\times Y$ and $V_{1}\subset X$
as well as $W_{1}\subset Y$ with $K\times L\subset U$, $K\subset V_{1}$
and $L\subset W_{1}$ and with
\begin{align*}
\lambda\left(K\times L\right) & \leq\lambda\left(U\right)<\lambda\left(K\times L\right)+\varepsilon,\\
\mu\left(K\right) & \leq\mu\left(V_{1}\right)<\mu\left(K\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\nu\left(L\right)},\\
\nu\left(L\right) & \leq\nu\left(W_{1}\right)<\nu\left(L\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\mu\left(K\right)}.
\end{align*}
By the Lemma, there are open sets $V_{2}\subset X$ and $W_{2}\subset Y$
with $K\times L\subset V_{2}\times W_{2}\subset U$. Set $V_{3}:=V_{1}\cap V_{2}$
and $W_{3}:=W_{1}\cap W_{2}$ and note $K\times L\subset V_{3}\times W_{3}\subset U$.
By Uryshon's Lemma, there are $\varphi\in C_{c}\left(X\right)$ and
$\psi\in C_{c}\left(Y\right)$ with $0\leq\varphi\leq1$, $0\leq\psi\leq1$
and $\varphi\equiv1$ on $K$ as well as ${\rm supp}\,\varphi\subset V_{3}$.
Analogously, $\psi\equiv1$ on $L$ and ${\rm supp}\,\psi\subset W_{3}$.
Define $\varphi\otimes\psi\left(x,y\right):=\varphi\left(x\right)\psi\left(y\right)$.
Then
$$
\mu\left(K\right)\nu\left(L\right)\leq\int\varphi\,{\rm d}\mu\cdot\int\psi\,{\rm d}\nu\leq\mu\left(V_{3}\right)\nu\left(W_{3}\right)\leq\mu\left(V_{1}\right)\nu\left(W_{1}\right)<\mu\left(K\right)\nu\left(L\right)+3\varepsilon.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\lambda\left(K\times L\right)\leq\int\varphi\otimes\psi\,{\rm d}\lambda\leq\lambda\left(V_{3}\times W_{3}\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\right)<\lambda\left(K\times L\right)+\varepsilon.
$$
But $\int\varphi\otimes\psi\,{\rm d}\lambda=\int\varphi\,{\rm d}\mu\cdot\int\psi\,{\rm d}\nu$,
which finally implies
$$
\left|\mu\left(K\right)\nu\left(L\right)-\lambda\left(K\times L\right)\right|\leq3\varepsilon+\left|\int\varphi\,{\rm d}\mu\cdot\int\psi\,{\rm d}\nu-\int\varphi\otimes\psi\,{\rm d}\lambda\right|+\varepsilon=4\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we obtain the claim for compact
sets $K,L$.

Now, let $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ be open and of finite measure.
Let $\alpha<\lambda\left(U\times V\right)$ be arbitrary. By inner
regularity of $\lambda$, there is a compact set $T\subset U\times V$
with $\alpha<\lambda\left(T\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\times V\right)$.
Let $\pi_{1}:X\times Y\to X$ be the usual projection and define $\pi_{2}$
analogously. Note that $K_{1}:=\pi_{1}\left(T\right)\subset U$ and
$L_{1}:=\pi_{2}\left(T\right)\subset V$ are compact with $T\subset K_{1}\times L_{1}\subset U\times V$.
Hence,
$$
\alpha<\lambda\left(T\right)\leq\lambda\left(K_{1}\times L_{1}\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\times V\right).
$$

By inner regularity of $\mu,\nu$, there are also compact sets $K_{2}\subset U$
and $L_{2}\subset V$ with

\begin{align*}
\mu\left(K_{2}\right) & \leq\mu\left(U\right)<\mu\left(K_{2}\right)+\varepsilon,\\
\nu\left(L_{2}\right) & \leq\nu\left(V\right)<\nu\left(L_{2}\right)+\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Now, let $K_{3}:=K_{1}\cup K_{2}$ and $L_{3}:=L_{1}\cup L_{2}$.
We then have $K_{3}\times L_{3}\subset U\times V$ and
$$
\alpha<\lambda\left(K_{1}\times L_{1}\right)\leq\lambda\left(K_{3}\times L_{3}\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\times V\right)
$$
as well as
$$
\alpha<\lambda\left(K_{3}\times L_{3}\right)=\mu\left(K_{3}\right)\nu\left(L_{3}\right)\leq\mu\left(U\right)\nu\left(V\right).
$$
Since $\alpha<\lambda\left(U\times V\right)$ was arbitrary, we see
$\lambda\left(U\times V\right)\leq\mu\left(U\right)\nu\left(V\right)<\infty$.

Furthermore, we get
$$
\left(\mu\left(U\right)-\varepsilon\right)\left(\nu\left(V\right)-\varepsilon\right)\leq\mu\left(K_{2}\right)\nu\left(L_{2}\right)\leq\mu\left(K_{3}\right)\nu\left(L_{3}\right)=\lambda\left(K_{3}\times L_{3}\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\times V\right).
$$
By sending $\varepsilon\downarrow0$, we see $\mu\left(U\right)\nu\left(V\right)\leq\lambda\left(U\times V\right)$
and hence
$$
\lambda\left(U\times V\right)=\mu\left(U\right)\nu\left(V\right)
$$
for all open sets $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ of finite measure.

Now, by $\sigma$-finiteness and outer regularity of $\mu,\nu$, we
can find increasing families $\left(U_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\left(V_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
of open sets with $X=\bigcup_{n}U_{n}$ and $Y=\bigcup_{n}V_{n}$
as well as $\mu\left(U_{n}\right)<\infty$ and $\nu\left(V_{n}\right)<\infty$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any open set $V\subset Y$ of finite measure,
$$
\mathcal{G}_{n,V}:=\left\{ M\subset X\,\mid\, M\text{ Borel and }\lambda\left(\left[M\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)=\mu\left(M\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right)\right\} .
$$
By what we just showed, $\mathcal{G}_{n,V}$ contains the $\pi$-system
of all open sets. Furthermore, it is not hard to see that $\mathcal{G}_{n,V}$
is closed under disjoint countable unions. Finally, for $M\in\mathcal{G}_{n,V}$,
we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda\left(\left[M^{c}\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)+\mu\left(M\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right) & =\lambda\left(\left[M^{c}\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)+\lambda\left(\left[M\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)\\
 & =\lambda\left(U_{n}\times V\right)\\
 & =\mu\left(U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right)\\
 & =\mu\left(M\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right)+\mu\left(M^{c}\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right),
\end{align*}
so that subtraction (everything is finite) shows $\lambda\left(\left[M^{c}\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)=\mu\left(M^{c}\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right)$
and hence $M^{c}\in\mathcal{G}_{n,V}$. Thus, $\mathcal{G}_{n,V}$
is a $\lambda$-system.

By Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$-Theorem, we conclude $\mathcal{G}_{n,V}=\mathcal{B}\left(X\right)$,
the $\sigma$-Algebra of all Borel sets. By continuity of $\lambda,\mu$
we thus get
$$
\lambda\left(M\times V\right)=\lim_{n}\lambda\left(\left[M\cap U_{n}\right]\times V\right)=\lim_{n}\mu\left(M\cap U_{n}\right)\nu\left(V\right)=\mu\left(M\right)\nu\left(V\right)
$$
for all Borel sets $M\subset X$ and all open sets $V\subset Y$ of
finite measure.

Now, define analogously
$$
\mathcal{H}_{m,M}:=\left\{ N\subset Y\,\mid\, N\text{ Borel and }\lambda\left(M\times\left[N\cap V_{m}\right]\right)=\mu\left(M\right)\cap\nu\left(N\cap V_{m}\right)\right\} 
$$
for each Borel set $M\subset X$ of finite measure. Just as above,
we see that $\mathcal{H}_{m,M}$ contains all open sets and then all
Borel sets. Using the same limit argument as above, we get 
$$
\mu\left(M\times N\right)=\mu\left(M\right)\nu\left(N\right)
$$
for all Borel sets $N\subset Y$ and all Borel sets $M\subset X$
of finite measure. A final limit argument (using $\sigma$-finiteness)
removes the assumption that $M$ has to have finite measure. $\square$

Comment: Thanks. By the way I would like to know whether Fubini's theorem holds for a Borel integrable function on $X\times Y$ or not. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @JHW: Yes, it does hold if the integrand $f(x,y)$ vanishes outside of a $\sigma$-finite set (I think, maybe it has to be $\sigma$-compact). One book in which this is shown is Folland's "Real Analysis". The argument is not quite trivial and proceeds through several lemmata. One of the steps is to show that $\int f \, d\mu = \sup \{\int g \, d\mu \, \mid \, g \in C_c, 0\leq g \leq f\}$ for a lower semicontinuous function $f \geq 0$ (in particular for $f = \chi_U$.

Comment: Fubini's theorem can be used as long as the function in question $f$ is measurable and has a $\sigma$--finite carrier (i.e. $E_f:=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:f(x,y)\neq0\}$ can be covered by countable integrable sets). Fubini--Tonelli's theorem then says: Suppose $f$ is measurable and has $\sigma$--finite carrier. $f$ is integrable iff any of the iterated integrals (and hence all) $\int_X\int_Y|f(x,y)|\mu(dy)\nu(dx)<\infty$ or $\int_Y\int_X|f(x,y)|\nu(dx)\mu(dy)<\infty$. In either case, $\int_{X\times Y}f d(\mu\otimes\nu) =\int_X\int_Y|f(x,y)|\mu(dy)\nu(dx)=\int_Y\int_X|f(x,y)|\nu(dx)\mu(dy)$.

Comment: The book by Donald L. Cohn deals this situation very elegantly. Chapter 7 is dedicated to this and he gives the condition on functions (similar to the one mentioned by oliver)  for fubini theorem to hold true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Lang's book is organized. But it is a general fact that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, if two measures agree as functionals on continuous functions, then they are equal. It is basically about using Urysohn to approximate characteristic functions by continuous functions.

**Edit:** after you show that $\lambda$ and $\mu\otimes\nu$ agree on compact sets, you know in particular that they agree on sets of the form $K_1\times K_2$, with $K_1\subset X$, $K_2\subset Y$, both compact.

From here, if $U\subset X$ is open, you have that $\mu(U)=\sup\{\mu(K):\ K\subset V,\ \text{compact }\}$. So
\begin{align}
\mu\otimes\nu(V\times K_2)&=\mu(V)\nu(K_2)=\sup\{\mu(K_1)\nu(K_2):\ K_1\subset V\}\\ 
&=\sup\{\mu\otimes\nu(K_1\otimes K_2):\ K_1\subset V\}\\
&=\sup\{\lambda(K_1\times K_2):\ K_1\subset V\}\\
&=\lambda(V\times K_2)
\end{align}
(the last equality because $\lambda$ is a Radon measure). By repeating the argument, you obtain that $\mu\otimes\nu$ and $\lambda$ agree on products of open sets. From here you fix an open set $W\in\mathcal B(Y)$ and consider the measures $E\longmapsto \mu\otimes\nu(E\times W)$ and $E\longmapsto \lambda(E\times W)$. These are two measures on $X$ that agree on open sets; as these generate $\mathcal B(X)$, we obtain that $\mu\otimes \nu(E\times W)=\lambda(E\times W)$ for all $E\in\mathcal B(X)$. With a similar argument, we get that $\mu\otimes\nu(E\times F)=\lambda(E\times F)$ for all $E\in\mathcal B(X)$, $F\in\mathcal B(Y)$. Then $\mu\otimes\nu$ and $\lambda$ agree on the sets that generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(Y)$.

Comment: Was just about to post something to this effect. You use inner regularity/Urysohn to conclude that they agree on all open sets of the form $U\times V$, for $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ open. It follows that they agree on $\mathcal{B}(X)\otimes \mathcal{B}(Y)$.

Comment: @Moya Would you please elaborate on why they agree on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes\mathcal B(Y)$?

Comment: "*if two measures agree as functionals on continuous functions, then they are equal.*"
Maybe they agree on compact subsets of $X\times Y$, but I don't see why they agree on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(X)$. Regards,

Comment: I don't think it is hard. Please see the edit.

Comment: Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
You seem to be saying that if two measures on $\mathcal B(X)$ agree on all open sets, they agree on $\mathcal B(X)$.
Would you please explain why this is so?

Comment: Because in this case the open sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. That's the whole point of using $\sigma$-algebras, that measures can be defined on the generating sets. See the [Dynkin $\pi$--$\lambda$ Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/813414/22857).

Comment: Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two measures on $\mathcal B(X)$.
Let $\mathcal L = \{E\in \mathcal B(X): \mu(E) = \nu(E)\}$.
How do you prove that $\mathcal L$ is a $\lambda$-system, i.e.
if $E\in \mathcal L$, then $E^c \in \mathcal L$?

Comment: I don't immediately see it. I assume it requires that $X$ is locally compact and that the two measures are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Then I suppose you need to prove that the two measures on $\mathcal B(X)$ in your **EDIT** are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: I'm wondering why you have been silent to my last comment.
I think it's crucial in your "proof" that you prove that the two measures in your **EDIT** are $\sigma$-finite. If you cannot prove that, please say so.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in the current context. In any case, the context you provided is not exactly the one in Lang's book. Right now I don't have the time to follow the reasoning trail in Lang's book.

Comment: "*In any case, the context you provided is not exactly the one in Lang's book*."
You seem to misunderstand.
I have just reproduced Theorem 6.3 and its proof for you.

Comment: I was talking about the context, not the theorem. When you defined Radon measure, you wrote property 3 for open sets. But in Lang's book he also includes  $\sigma $-finite sets.

Comment: We can prove by using our definition of Radon measures that the property 3 includes $\sigma$-finite sets. I thought this is well known. In any case you know that right now.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @MartinArgerami's argument, you want to prove that if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two Radon measures on $X$ which agree on continuous functions, then they agree on all Borel sets. To do this, it suffices (by inner regularity) to prove that $\mu_1(K) = \mu_2(K)$ for all compacts $K \subset X$. For this you need the following lemma:

> Lemma: Let $K \subset X$ be a compact set, then $\exists \varphi : X\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous bounded such that
>   $$
> \varphi \equiv 1 \text{ on } K \text{ and } \varphi < 1 \text{ on } X\setminus K
> $$
>   Proof: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let
>   $$
> G_n = \{x \in X : d(x,K) <  1/n\}
> $$
>   there is a function $\varphi_n : X\to [0,1]$ such that
>   $$
> \varphi_0 \equiv 1 \text{ on } K \text{ and } \varphi_n \equiv 0 \text{ on } X\setminus G_n
> $$
>   Now check that
>   $$
> \varphi = \sum \frac{1}{2^n} \varphi_n
> $$
>   satisfies the required properties.

---

Now to complete the argument: If
$$
\int_X f d\mu_1 = \int_X fd\mu_2 \quad\forall f\in C(X)
$$
then for $K \subset X$ compact, choose a function $\varphi$ as above. Now note that
$$
\varphi^n \to \chi_K
$$
pointwise. So now you can apply Dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $\mu_1(K) = \mu_2(K)$

Comment: Thanks. Maybe $\lambda$ and $\mu\otimes\nu$ agree on compact subsets of $X\times Y$, but I don't see why they agree on $\mathcal B(X)\otimes \mathcal B(X)$. Regards,

Comment: I'm wondering why you have been silent to my last comment.

Comment: I assumed that @MartinArgerami answered you fine in the edit he made to this post.

Comment: He didn't answer me fine in the edit. Please read my comments to him about it.

Comment: This is not correct: 1) You seem to assume that there is some kind of metric on $X$, which is not true in general. $X$ might not even be first countable. 2) We do not know that the measure $\mu \otimes \nu$ is Radon. In general, it is not even defined on the whole Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$.